# Find the remainder of $3^{333}$ divided by $100$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

> Find the remainder of $3^{333}$ divided by $100$

So I can find that $100=2^2\cdot 5^2$

Then I want to find $3^{333}$ mod $4$ and mod $25$ and use chinese remainder theorem to find a solution mod $100$.

I can find that $3^{333}\equiv (-1)$ mod $4$

But then $3^{333}=((3^3)^3)^{37}\equiv (27^3)^{37}\equiv (2^3)^{37}\equiv 8^{37}$ mod $25$

But I cannot find $8^{37}$ mod $25$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: @WhatsUp I can see I can reduce it to $3^{320}\times 3^{13}\equiv 3^{13}$ mod $100$, but not sure what I do with $3^{13}$

Comment: You used the first link I gave. Now use the second one.

Comment: $3^{20}=3 486 784 401\equiv 1 \text{ mod }100$. Just a little hint :)

Comment: On a more simple approach, making a table will take some time, but it doesn't let you down: $3^1$ and $3^{21}$ have the same remainder of $3$ when dividing by $100$. To extend it to the power $333$ is mere artihmatic

Comment: **Hint** $\large\ 3^{333} = 3(-1+10)^{166} =\,\ldots$ (Binomial Theorem, only first two terms survive $\bmod 100$)

Comment: @imranfat Why does $3^{21}$ have remainder $3$? Shouldn't $3^{41}$ be the smallest power that has remainder $3$?

Comment: Because $3^{21}=10460353203$

Comment: @imranfat Besides computing it?

Comment: @AColoredReptile $40$ is the cardinality of the multiplicative group of integers $\pmod{100}$, so the order of $3$ in it is a divisor of $40$ by Lagrange's theorem. It turns out to be $20$ and I don't think there is an easy way to know besides computation

Comment: @Evariste Ok, but if I could compute $3^{21}$ I could compute $8^{37}$ so I kind of view that as being the same problem.

Comment: @AColoredReptile Well in most cases you're going to need to compute a little bit. You started well by reducing to the case of powers of $2$ as they are easy to compute. Just compute the powers until you get something close enough to a multiple of $25$ like I did and then the calculation becomes easy. $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024$ takes split seconds to compute and $1024$ is obviously pretty close to being a multiple of $25$. I wouldn't recommend trying to find which powers of $3$ reduces to $1$ as it takes a long time. Just try to reduce the exponent by computing intermediary steps

Comment: $\!\!\large \bmod 25\!:\ 3^{13}\equiv 3(\color{#c00}{3^3})^4 \equiv 3(\color{#c00}{2})^4 \equiv 23,\,$ and already $\large \,23\equiv -1\pmod{\!4}$ hence $23$ is the sought  CRT solution (since the solution is *unique* $\!\bmod 100$ by CRT).

Comment: Modulo $100$ we have $3^4\equiv 81$,... so $3^8\equiv (3^4)^2\equiv 81^2\equiv 61$,.. so $3^{12}\equiv 3^8\cdot 3^4\equiv 61\cdot 81\equiv 41$,... so $3^{13}\equiv 3^{12}\cdot 3  \equiv 41\cdot 3 \equiv 23.$

Comment: "but not sure what I do with $3^{13}$".  1) If $3^{20}\equiv 1\pmod {25}$ then $3^{10}$ is most likely to be $\equiv \pm 1$.  2) If $3^{20}\equiv 1$ then $3^{13}\equiv 3^{-7}$.  3) multiple squaring should be intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need, as you noted, $3^{13}\pmod {100}$.  Try successive squaring.  $3^2=9,3^4=9^2=81,3^8=81^2=(-19)^2=61, 3^{12}=3^4\cdot3^8=81\cdot61=41,3^{13}=3\cdot41=23\pmod{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $3^{333} \equiv 2^{111}\equiv1024^{11}\times2\equiv-2 \pmod{25}$ (note that I used your calculation for the first equality here and the well-known fact that $2^{10}=1024$)

So, if $x=3^{333}$, $x=-2+25k \equiv-2+k \equiv-1 \pmod4$

Hence $k \equiv1 \pmod 4$

Therefore $x=-2+25(1+4k')=23+100k' \equiv23 \pmod{100}$

Answer (score 1):

$3^{333}$ being divided by 100.

$=(3^9)^{37}$

$=19683^{37}$

$=(19700-17)^{37}$

$\equiv -17^{37} \quad \bmod 100$

$-17^{37} =-17(17^{36})=-17(300-11)^{18}$

$\equiv -17(11^{18}) \quad \bmod 100$

$-17(11^{18})=-17((1300+31)^6)$

$\equiv -17(31^6) \quad \bmod 100$

$-17(31^6)=-17(1000-39)^3$

$\equiv -17 \cdot -39^3 \quad \bmod 100$

$17 \cdot 39^3=17 \cdot 39 \cdot (1500+21)$

$=(700-37)(1500+21)$

And after all the work $-37 \cdot 21=-777 \equiv -77 (\bmod 100)$

But if the answer had to be positive then $100-77=\boxed{23}$

Answer (score 0):

Use the totient function.  $2$ and $5$ are distinct primes so $\phi(100)=\phi(2^25^2)=\phi(2^2)\phi(5^2)=[2(2-1)][5(5-1)]=40.$

Now since $\gcd(3,100)=1$ we have $1\equiv 3^{\phi(100)}\equiv 3^{40} \mod 100.$

Therefore $3^{333}\equiv (3^{40})^8\cdot 3^{13}\equiv (1)^8\cdot 3^{13}\equiv 3^{13} \mod 100.$

To finish, see my comment to the Q.

Answer (score 0):

$4\mid 100\:$ & $\:4\mid \color{#90f}{3^{333}}\!+1\,$ (by $\bmod 4\!:\ 3^{333}\!+1\equiv (-1)^{333}\!+1\equiv -1+1\equiv 0),\,$ so

using $\ ab\bmod ac = a\,(b\bmod c) = $ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor out $\,a = 4$

$3^{\large 333}\!+\!1\bmod 100 = 4\left[\dfrac{\color{#90f}{3^{\large 333}}\!+\!1}4\bmod 25\right] = 4\left[\dfrac{\color{#90f}{23}\!+\!1}4\bmod 25\right] = 4[6],\ $ by

$\!\bmod 25\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{3^{\large 20}\equiv 1}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#90f}{3^{\large 333}}\equiv \underbrace{3(\color{#0a0}{3^{\large 3}})^{\large 4}(\color{#c00}{3^{\large 20}})^{\large 16}}_{\textstyle 3\,(\color{#0a0}2)^{\large 4}\,\color{#c00}1^{\large 16}}\equiv \color{#90f}{23},\,$ by $\rm\color{#c00}{Euler\ \phi(5^2)=4\cdot 5}$

**Remark** $ $ The computation of $\,\color{#90f}{3^{333}}\bmod 25\,$ in the prior line is a special case of the method of [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) - the key to simplifying the computation of large modular powers.

As explained in the first link, the mod Distributive Law is an *operational* form of CRT. We can use the standard CRT formula along with the above computation mod $25$ to obtain the same result. In fact *already* $23\equiv -1\pmod{\!4}$ so we're done - we don't even need to apply the CRT formula.

Another quick way: $\, 3^{\large 333} = 3(-1+10)^{\large 166} =\,\ldots\,$ so expanding by Binomial Theorem shows only the first $2$ terms survive $\!\bmod 100 = 10^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Use Euler.

$\phi(25) = 20$ so $8^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod {25}$

So we need to figure out $8^{17}\equiv 8^{-3}$ which is which will be equivalent to $k^3$ where $k$ is the multiplicative inverse of $8$.  $8*3=24\equiv -1$ so $8*(-3)\equiv 1 \pmod{25}$ and $8^{17} \equiv (-3)^3 \equiv -27\equiv -2\equiv 23 \pmod {25}$.

.....

Or back to the $3$

$3^{333}=3^{320}3^{13}\equiv 3^{13}\pmod {25}$.

As $3^{20}\equiv 1$ its a good guess that $3^{10} \equiv \pm 1$.

Many ways to do this but $3^{10} = 3^3*3^3*3^3*3\equiv 27*27*27*3\equiv 2*2*2*3\equiv 24 \equiv -1 \pmod {20}$.  So $3^{13}\equiv -3^3\equiv -27\equiv -2 \equiv 23$.

.....OR.....

$100 = 10^2$

$3^2 = 10-1$

So $3^{10} = (10-1)^5\equiv 50-1$

$3^{20} \equiv (50-1)^2 \equiv 1\pmod {100}$.

So $3^{333}\equiv 3^{13}\equiv 3^{10}*3^{3}\equiv (50-1)*27\equiv 50*(26+1)-27\equiv 50 - 27 \equiv 23\pmod{100}$